# Bootstrap Center of the page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good day everyone, I want my bootstrap page to be centered in the center. How will I do it with this format

[image: The outer box is the display and I want my page to be centered. All of the elements.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to get this format.

- By using `position:absolute;` and `top` ,`left` values to the navigation menu
- Using `container` class and perspective `col` value
- using  `margin:0 auto;` `display:table;` to the navigation menu

Comment: No thanks... Glad to help :) .. If your problem cleared means you can accept as answer...

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS as below

```
 div {
           position: absolute;
           top: 0;
           left: 0;
           bottom: 0;
           right: 0;
           margin: auto;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use col-sm-offset-# where # is how much you would want it to offset by. Notice, this will not automatically center all contents within contents, but it will put

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
```

in the center of the page. As for the "Hello world" you need separate css t0 center that. In this example since, the column system in bootstrap is based on 12 columns, if your main div is 8 columns wide and the offset is 2 columns, it will therefore center the div.

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
   <div class="jumbotron">
     <h1> Hello World </h1>
   </div>
 </div>
```